# ASM GLFW Окно чёрное или вообще закрывается

Tags: ассемблер

Пишу программу на языке ассемблера. Код отрисовки окна вот такой:

```
drawLoop PROC
    sub rsp, 240                 ; Выравниваем стек

    mov rcx, handle
    call glfwWindowShouldClose  ; Проверяем нужно ли закрывать окно
    test rax, rax
    jnz finish                  ; Если нужно, то закрываем


    mov rcx, 1
    mov rdx, 1
    mov r8, 1
    mov r9d, 1
    call glColor4i

    mov rcx, 3042 ; GL_BLEND
    call glEnable

    mov rcx, 3553 ; GL_TEXTURE_2D
    call glDisable

    mov rcx, 770 ; GL_SRC_ALPHA
    mov rdx, 771 ; GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA
    call glBlendFunc

    mov rcx, 7 ; GL_QUADS
    call glBegin
        mov rcx, 0
        mov rdx, 0
        call glVertex2i

        mov rcx, 0
        mov rdx, 480
        call glVertex2i

        mov rcx, 640
        mov rdx, 480
        call glVertex2i

        mov rcx, 640
        mov rdx, 0
        call glVertex2i
    call glEnd

    mov rcx, 3042 ; GL_BLEND
    call glDisable

    mov rcx, 3553 ; GL_TEXTURE_2D
    call glEnable

    mov rcx, handle
    call glfwSwapBuffers
    call glfwPollEvents         ; Обрабатываем евенты и swap-buffer

    add rsp, 240

    jmp drawLoop                ; Переходим обратно в начало drawLoop, чтобы сделать цикл
drawLoop endp
```

По факту, он должен заливать полностью окно белым цветом, но я вижу чёрное окно:

[image: window]

Если посмотреть псевдо вид в IDA x64:

[image: ida pseudocode]

То выглядит как-будто всё так и должно быть

Также, если заменить `jmp drawLoop` на `call drawLoop`, то белый цвет будет виден буквально на секунду и окно закроется. Почему так происходит и как это починить? Все extern и includelib находятся в отдельном файле (если кто-то будет спрашивать про них, хотя вряд ли)

- ОС: Windows x64
- Компилятор / линковщик: MASM elf64

Comment: `glColor4i(1, 1, 1, 1)` - это почти черный цвет. `jmp drawLoop` переходит не в начало цикла, а в начло процедуры. ¿На каком шаге закрывается окно?

Comment: @AlexF не помогло. user7860670 заменил всё на 255, тупанул, но ошибка осталась. Ещё не научился запускать дебаг, так что не знаю когда закрывается. Ещё если убрать вызов drawLoop, то окно не закроется, но если убрать drawLoop вообще, то начнёт закрываться.

Answer (score 0):

Заменил glColor4i на glColor4f помогло